# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'inputemail' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have my form, When I press the button submit I call to my controller users to the method Create, for add one user.

The route go to the controller and then I get one error unknown column inputemail

```
@section('modal_body')
    {{ Form::open(array('id' =>'formuser-create', 'role' => 'form', 'url' =>'users/create', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('inputuser', 'Nombre de usuario', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::text('inputuser','', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce la contraseña...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }}   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('inputpassword', 'Contraseña', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::password('inputpassword','', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce la contraseña...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('inputpassword1', 'Confirmar constraseña', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::password('inputpassword1','', array('placeholder' => 'Vuelve a introducir la contraseña...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('inputemail', 'Email', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::text('inputemail','', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce el email...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }} 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('es_admin', '¿Es administrador?', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::checkbox('es_admin',1,false) }}
                </div>
            </div>

@stop
@section('modal_footer')
<div class='form-group text-center' id='editor-actions'>
    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }} 
    {{ Form::reset('Limpiar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}  
</div>
@stop
@endif
```

I call to my controller

```
Route::Controller('users','UsersController');
```

The code of my controller is

```
     <?php

class UsersController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth'); //bloqueo de acceso
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $my_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $is_admin = Auth::user()->admin;
        //control permissions only access administrator
        if($is_admin==1)
        {
            $users = User::where('admin', '<>', '1')->where('id', '<>', $my_id)->get();
            return View::make('admin/users.index')->with('users',$users);
        }
        else
        {
            return View::make('errors.access_denied');
        }
    }

    //metodo para agregar al usuario
    public function postCreate()
    {
        //validamos reglas inputs
        $rules = array(
          'inputuser' => 'required|max:10',
          'inputpassword' => 'required|min:8',
          'inputpassword1' => 'required|min:8',
          'inputemail' => 'required|email|unique:users'
        );

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        //Si no pasa la validacion
        if($validation->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->with_input()->with_errors($validation);
        }
        //Si todo ha ido bien guardamos
        $password = Input::get('inputpassword');
        $user = new User;
        $user->username = Input::get('inputuser');
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->email = Input::get('inputemail');
        $user->admin = Input::get('es_admin');

        //guardamos
        $user->save();

        //redirigimos a usuarios

        return Redirect::to('admin/users.index')->with('status','ok_create');

    }
}
```

I get the following errors trace

I

```
lluminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'inputemail' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `inputemail` = mangulomx@gmail.com)"

Stacktrace:
#35 Illuminate\Database\QueryException in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:625
#34 UsersController:postCreate in <#unknown>:0
#33 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in <#unknown>:0
#32 PDOException in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:299
#31 PDO:prepare in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:299
#30 Illuminate\Database\Connection:Illuminate\Database\{closure} in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:617
#29 Illuminate\Database\Connection:runQueryCallback in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:581
#28 Illuminate\Database\Connection:run in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:304
#27 Illuminate\Database\Connection:select in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:1412
#26 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:runSelect in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:1397
#25 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:getFresh in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:1384
#24 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:get in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:1830
#23 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:aggregate in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:1768
#22 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:count in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier.php:57
#21 Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier:getCount in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:1020
#20 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:validateUnique in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:322
#19 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:validate in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:283
#18 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:passes in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:297
#17 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:fails in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\app\controllers\UsersController.php:38
#16 UsersController:postCreate in <#unknown>:0
#15 call_user_func_array in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:231
#14 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:callAction in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:93
#13 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:call in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:62
#12 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:967
#11 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in <#unknown>:0
#10 call_user_func_array in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:109
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:1033
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:1001
#7 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:775
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:745
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php:72
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php:47
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php:51
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:641
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in C:\wamp\www\viversoft\public\index.php:49
```

I dont understand because unknown colum 'inputemail'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs of the `unique` rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-unique):

> `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`
>
> The field under validation must be unique on a given database table. If the `column` option is not specified, the field name will be used.

Since your input name is different from the column name in the database you have to specify it:

```
'inputemail' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'
//                                           ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very usefull!